# How to use JCommandCentre to display a JFR recoding on a remote server?

Tags: docker, jfr

How do I use JCommandCentre for a JFR recording on a remote server.
To be more clear I have a docker container running java 11, where a JFR recording is already in progress.

```
JPID=118
jcmd $JPID JFR.configure repositorypath=/tmp/jcmdrecording/
jcmd $JPID JFR.start name=recording1 filename=JFRfile.jfr disk=true dumponexit=true  maxage=1d maxsize=200m  path-to-gc-roots=true
jcmd $JPID JFR.check
```

Now, in the JCommandCentre it seems that it's expecting some open port 7091.
Is this port automatically started by JFR? And I'm suppose to port-forward my docker port 7091 to my localhost 7091?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the management agent. You can do this when the application starts or using jcmd.

If you don't care about security on startup.

```
 java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
      ...
```

Using jcmd:

```
jcmd $JPID ManagementAgent.start
     jmxremote.port=7091
     jmxremote.ssl=false
     jmxremote.authenticate=false
```